# Mixing post- and pre- increment/decrement operators on the same variable

Tags: c++, c, increment, decrement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is ++i considered an l-value, but i++ is not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371503/why-is-i-considered-an-l-value-but-i-is-not)

In C++ (and also in C), if I write:

```
++x--
++(x--)
```

i get the error: lvalue required as increment operand

However `(++x)--` compiles. I am confused.

Comment: Please don't do this it hurts my eyes. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371503/why-is-i-considered-an-l-value-but-i-is-not

Comment: `gcc` will not compile `(++x)--` here, `g++` will. Same holds for `++i = 5;`

Comment: That really shouldn't compile. What compiler are you using, so I know to avoid it?

Comment: In C++ `(++x)--` is syntactically correct but invokes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Nathon: yes, it should compile. (The standard definition of operator ++ in a custom iterator class is `iterator & operator++  ()`)

Comment: @Prasoon: prove to me that's undefined. The semantics of how that works on a custom iterator class are quite clear.

Comment: @Ken: The variable `x` is being modified more than once between two sequence points and so the behavior is undefined in this case. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Prasoon: There's a sequence point before the function call of the `operator--`. There is also a sequence point after the `operator++` returns.

Comment: @Ken: Where did he mention that `x` is an object and not a primitive type? `C` the tags :P

Comment: @Ken. Who cares if for some bazare instance it is valid. In most instances it is undefined. But most importantly it is hard to read and understand and for that reason alone it should not be used.

Comment: This actually raises an interesting question of why we don't define `operator++` to return a const reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Post- and pre-increment operators only work on lvalues.

When you call `++i` the value of `i` is incremented and then `i` is returned. In C++ the return value is the variable and is an lvalue.

When you call `i++` (or `i--`) the return value is the value of `i` before it was incremented. This is a **copy** of the old value and doesn't correspond to the variable `i` so it cannot be used as an lvalue.

Anyway don't do this, even if it compiles.

Comment: @Jerry: I just fixed it for him, along with one other minor edit.

Comment: +1 for `Don't do this, even if it compiles.`. :-)