# Why Pointer assignment shows lvalue error when assignments look appropriate?

Tags: c, pointers, lvalue

I am given a piece of code for which we have to guess output.

My Output: 60

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int d[] = {20,30,40,50,60};
    int *u,k;
    u = d;
    k = *((++u)++);
    k += k;
    (++u) += k;

    printf("%d",*(++u));

    return 0;
}
```

Expected: 
`k = *((++u)++)` will be equal to 30 as it will iterate once(++u) and then will be iterated but not assigned. So we are in d[1].

`(++u) += k` here u will iterate to next position, add k to it and then assign the result to further next element of u.

Actual result:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:16:16: error: lvalue required as increment operand
     k = *((++u)++);
                ^
main.c:18:11: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     (++u) += k;
```

And this has confused me further in concepts of pointers. Please help.

Comment: _"I am given a piece of code for which we have to guess output."_ By whom? In what context? Are you sure you were supposed to write C?

Comment: The issues you face are not related to pointers in any way. They are only related to pre-increment operator. You don't need to worry about your knowledge about pointers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit 
Yes I was supposed to write in C and this question is from a test

Comment: @Gerhardh thanks for specifying that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the compiler has told you, the program is not valid C.

[In C, pre-increment results in an *rvalue* expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4802315/560648), which you may not assign to or increment.

It's not a logical problem; it's a language problem. You should split that complex formula into multiple code statements.

That's all there is to it.

(In C++ it's an *lvalue* though and you can do both those things.)

Comment: It would be rude not to upvote this. Funny how we both write the bit about C++ at the end.

Comment: @Bathsheba Anyways `*((++u)++);` looks like an expression to avoid, unless this is some learning exercise..

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah, it should be avoided. But it was a learning exercise.

Answer (score 6):

In C, `++a` is *not* an l-value.

Informally this means that you can't have it on the left hand side of an assignment.

It also means that you can't increment it.

So `(++a)++` is invalid code.

(Note that it is valid C++).

Comment: It would be rude not to upvote this. Funny how we both write the bit about C++ at the end.