# Post increment operator ++

Tags: c++

```
cout<<(x++)++; //fails 
cout<<++(++x); //passes
```

Why does the post increment fail ? I see it happen but not sure of the technical reason.

Comment: post-incrementing a temporary?

Comment: What's the type of `x`? That matters a lot. If it's a built-in, `operator++` is not a function call.

Answer (score 13):

`x++` returns an rvalue so you can't perform `++` again on it. On the other hand, `++x` returns an lvalue so you can perform `++` on it.

Comment: also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371503/why-is-i-considered-an-l-value-but-i-is-not)

Answer (score 4):

This is how the increment operators work in C/C++.

If you put the `++` after the variable (postfix increment), the whole expression evaluates to the value of the variable *before* incrementing.

If you put the `++` before the variable (prefix increment), the expression evaluates to the value after the increment operation.

While the prefix operation returns a reference to the passed variable, the postfix version returns a temporary value, which must not be incremented.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. yo cannot perform a ++ over an Rvalue. a good explanation about how rvalue works is given [here](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html).