# Indifferent behavior of C++ code snippet

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Consider the following code snippet

```
int a,i;  
a = 5;  
(i++) = a;  
(++i) = a;  
cout<<i<<endl;
```

Line `(++i) = a` is compiling properly and giving 5 as output.
But  `(i++) = a` is giving compilation error `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`.

I am not able to find the reason for such indifferent behavior. I would be grateful if someone explains this.

Comment: `i++` returns an rvalue of built-in type - they're not modifiable.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371503/why-is-i-considered-an-l-value-but-i-is-not

Comment: Removed C tag - neither assignments are valid in C (and obviously the last line isn't C either). Also you've got undefined behavior I believe on (i++) even if it did somehow compile, since i is uninitialized.

Comment: excellent read on lvalues and rvalues [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx).

Comment: @Mat On the other hand, it probably is worth pointing out that this _is_ one place where C and C++ differ.  (And of course, both lines _are_ illegal in both languages.  The only difference is that the second doesn't require a compiler diagnostic in C++; it's still undefined behavior.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `i++` evaluates to the value of `i` prior to the increment operation. That value is a temporary (which is an *rvalue*) and you cannot assign to it.

`++i` works because that expression evaluates to `i` after it has been incremented, and `i` can be assigned to (it's an *lvalue*).

[More on lvalues and rvalues on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: ah i think the lvalueness and rvalueness has been interchanged here.

Comment: @Koushik Yep. That's what happens when your first thing in the morning isn't making coffee or brushing your teeth, but loading up a project in your IDE and then looking something up on SO, and since one thing leads to another... :-P

Comment: Of course, the real reason why one is an lvalue, and the other not, is because the (C++) standard says so.  But your explication does hit on the basic logic used in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ standard, prefix `++` is an lvalue (which
is different than C), post-fix no.  More generally, C++ takes
the point of view that anything which changes an lvalue
parameter, and has as its value the value of that parameter,
results in an lvalue.  So `++ i` is an lvalue (since the
resulting value is the new value of `i`), but `i ++` is not
(since the resulting value is *not* the new value, but the old).

All of this, of course, for the built-in `++` operators.  If you
overload, it depends on the signatures of your overloads (but
a correctly designed overloaded `++` will behave like the
built-in ones).

Of course, neither `(++ i) = a;` nor `(i ++) = a;` in your
example are legal; both use the value of an uninitialized
variable (`i`), which is undefined behavior, and both modify `i`
twice without an intervening sequence point.