# Practical uses of the fact that the C++ prefix increment operator returns an lvalue

Tags: c++, c++11

I have just learned that the result of the prefix increment operator in C++ is an lvalue. There are probably cases where this behavior helps the programmer be more effective, but I could not think of any. What are some idiomatic uses of this behavior of the prefix increment operator?

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate...as to in what context you are measuring efficiency.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/371669/567292

Comment: Thank you. I missed that post in my research before posting the question. By effectiveness I mean concise and clear code that would not be such had the feature not been present in the language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is ++i considered an l-value, but i++ is not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371503/why-is-i-considered-an-l-value-but-i-is-not)

Answer (score 6):

The reason prefix `++` returns an lvalue is orthogonality; I've not seen
any use for it that wouldn't qualify as obfuscation.  But the question
is: what rules apply to cause an expression to be an lvalue.  In C, the
basic rule is that expressions which modify one of their operands aren't
lvalues, but a number of people wanted to support things like:

```
T&
someFunction( T& lhs, T const& rhs )
{
    //  ...
    return lhs = rhs;
}
```

This works for user defined types (because `operator=` will be a member
function), and some members wanted to support it for built-in types as
well.  So the basic rule became: if an operator required an lvalue
operand, which it modified, *and* the results of the operator were the
changed operand, then it is an lvalue.  (Thus, while prefix `++` is an
lvalue, postfix isn't, because the results of the expression aren't the
changed operand.)

Personally, I'm not sure I agree.  I have no problem with replacing the
above with:

```
T&
someFunction( T& lhs, T const& rhs )
{
    //  ...
    lhs = rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

which is how I'd write it in my own code.  But given that the first
example is legal for user defined types (where `operator=` returns
a `T&`), and that a number of committee members did like it, it seems
logical to extend it to the built-in types, and the resulting rule is
coherent, even if no one ever actually has the occasion to use the
results of prefix `++` as an lvalue.

EDIT:

Just to make it clear: I asked this very question at one of the
meetings (when we were defining C++ 98), and this was the
response I got (from, if I recall correctly, Andy Koenig, who
worked with Stroustrup on the earliest implementations of C++).
It was also the justification for having the default
implementation of `operator=` return a `T&` rather than a
`T const&`.

Answer (score 4):

The change from C where ++x is an rvalue to C++ where ++x for built-in types is an lvalue is probably because there are much more useful applications. For example, you might define a function alternatively as

```
void f (int x);
void f (int& x);
```

and the fact that ++x is an lvalue allows you to call f (++x); in either case. In C, only the first case was legal, and works just fine with an rvalue. In C++, you want an lvalue.

Comment: I think a case with `int f(int x);` and `int& f(int& x);` would be a bit clearer of an example. By returning an lvalue when given an lvalue, the argument's lvalue-ness is preserved through the function, instead of everything being forced to an rvalue. So it would be surprising if feeding `++x` to the function suddenly called the rvalue version of the function instead.

Comment: The clearest example would be `int const& f(int const&)` and `int& f(int&`)`.  But this leads to `f(i++)` calling the first, and `f(++i)` the second, which is more of an argument for _not_ making prefix `++` an lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

```
i=9;
j=10;
k = ((i)>(j))?(j):(++i);
```

In the above case we have a use of prefix increment operator as you can c we first check i>j which will be false in this case then we are assigning the value ++i to k which will give us k=1.
Here in one single statement we have used i twice but once the value was 9 and other time the value was 10.
If you try to achieve this without prefix increment operator we would have to use another temporary variable to store to the value of i then increment i to assign to k.
Without using prefix operator

```
  i=9;
 j=10;
Temp=i;
 i=i+1;
k = ((Temp)>(j))?(j):(i);
```

Still if we arrive at a conditin where temp is greter than j then we will have the value of i incremented even if we dont use it. Using prefix operator tje value of i will only increment if i less than j.

Comment: The OP asked about the use of ++i as an lvalue. Your first code is just as fine in C, where ++i is _not_ an lvalue.