# why does if(++x=++y) works and if(x++=++y) does not work?

Tags: c++, operators

when i am executing this program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int x=5,y=9;

    if(++x=y++){
        cout<<"Works "<<x;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"No";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it works fine and the output is: Works 9

but if i execute:

```
  #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int x=5,y=9;

    if(x++=y++){
        cout<<"Works "<<x;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"No";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it states:
 In function 'int main()':
6:11: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     if(x++=y++){

Comment: @BoBTFish so is `++x` an lvalue? weird

Comment: The operator for comparison is `==` and not `=`. So it's difficult to understad what you are trying to accomplish. That said, it is an interesting question

Comment: `++x` is an lvalue, but if you assign to it, you invoke undefined behaviour (two modifications without an intervening sequence point in the language of C and C++89.)

Comment: Because both(x++ and ++y) are not of the same type and you need == for comparison.

Comment: You should remove the `if`s, because they are confusing everyone.

Comment: i am trying to check the boolean result when this expression is evaluated and thus "if" is necessary @juanchopanza

Comment: @Dreamer what do you mean by not of same types? even "if(++x=++y)" would work

Comment: What kind of result are you expecting to evaluate with your if? Try setting y=0 in the first snippet, x is correctly assigned the value of y and the ouput is "No"

Comment: By same type I meant prefix and postfix cannot be compared as they both are different. Likewise, you cannot compare int and string. @AttyuttamSaha

Comment: @AttyuttamSaha What you're trying to do doesn't matter. What matters is the specific question you're asking here (basically, why doesn't `x++ = ++y` compile.) Removing irrelevant code and information improves the clarity of a question.

Comment: @Dreamer Of course a suffix and a prefix expression can be compared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `x++` isn't an lvalue.

More specifically, `x++` increments `x`, then returns a *temporary* with the original value of `x`. A temporary object can't (casts of dubious legality aside) be used on the left hand side of an assignment, so it is not an lvalue.

`++x` increments `x` and returns a reference to `x` (with its new value). You can then assign directly to it if you choose, so it is an lvalue.

However, it is possible you actually meant to compare the two expressions for equality, rather than do an assignment. In which case, you need to use `==` rather than `=`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember that the suffix increment operator returns the *old* value, before the increment.

This value is a very temporary value, and as all other temporary values it is not an "lvalue", i.e. it is not something that can be assigned to.

The prefix increment operator does its increment operation, and then return a reference to the new value. For `++x` it returns a reference to `x`. It *is* an "lvalue".

The same of course goes for the decrement (`--`) operator.

There are many sources all over the Internet that will help you understand the difference between "lvalues" and "rvalues" (temporaries).

Comment: Have I missed something?  How is the first example not UB?

Comment: @MartinBonner It would be if it was e.g. `++x=x++` then yes it would be UB. But now the OP is using two different variables so it's okay.

Comment: ?? Why?  There is the increment of x, and there is the assignment to x.  That's two modifications and no intervening sequence point (or whatever the equivalent terminology in C++11 onward is).

Comment: @MartinBonner Here it's a question about normal [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The increment operators have much higher precedence than assignment, and therefore will be done first. The prefix increment operator returns a reference to the incremented `x`, and this reference can be used as the left-hand side of an assignment normally.

Comment: No, that's *definitely* wrong.  operator precedence defines what is being operated on (eg `a / b + c` means the operands to `/` are `a` and `b`, not `b+c`), not the ordering of side effects.  I will have to look up the wording and quote the relevant sections in my answer.

Comment: @MartinBonner In my mind `++x = y++` is equivalent to `(++x) = y++`, which is why I claim that it's a operator precedence issue. I might be wrong of course (I have been wrong before :)) and will gladly admit defeat if you are able to find something to back you up.

Answer (score 1):

x++ returns x, and then increments x. On the other hand, ++x increments x, and then returns it.

The second case makes sense; x is being returned, and you can do whatever. The first case makes no sense at all; x++ isn't a value. In fact, once you get back the value, x is no longer that value.

Answer (score 1):

As everybody else has explained, the value of `x++` is a temporary containing the old value of `x`, and temporaries cannot be assigned to.  The compiler therefor rejects the code as not conforming to the grammar of C++.

The problem you have is that the *first* example is also wrong.  Although `++x` is grammatically an lvalue, if you put it on the left hand side of an assignment operator, you are both incrementing `x` *and* assigning to `x`, and it's not clear what you meant to happen.  C++89 and C have the concept of sequence points, and if you modify the same variable twice without an intervening sequence point - the behaviour of the program is not defined (*anything* can happen - including replacing the whole function with `return`, or a segfault).

C++11 introduced a different terminology which I am not familiar with, but the effect in this case is the same - your first example is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Add some brackets according to operator precedence to see what is going on:

```
(++x) = (y++)
```

This increments x, increments y and assigns y-1 (previous value of y before the increment) to x (y++ evaluates to y, since it is a post-increment here)

```
(x++)=(y++)
```

This here isn't a valid statement, since x++ doesn't have an lvalue.

See also: [Why is ++i considered an l-value, but i++ is not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371503/why-is-i-considered-an-l-value-but-i-is-not)