# Differences between prefix-increment operator in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

I just read the [C reference about prefix increment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_incdec) and realized that the result of prefix increment operator are not lvalue, but it's surprising that it is lvalue in C++. After that I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/371669/7813604) which explaining why it's a lvalue, but I don't understand it:

> (Line 3): *["] it appears that it is so you can take its address or assign to a reference. [."]*

and an example follows:

> ```
> int i;
> extern void f (int* p);
>
> f (&++i);   /* Would be illegal C, but C programmers
>               havent missed this feature */
> ...
> ```

So what's the merit of allowing this? Is the only purpose of this that incrementing `i` in global region is illegal? If this is the only reason I would consider this be a remedy for a defect in C that cannot/hard to be resolved, or the program should probably be rewritten for the sake of readability, right?

btw I don't understand why lvalue is also called "locator value", I've read [this - line 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkbs2cds.aspx) but locator is vague for me. What's a locator, is it a pointer something?

**EDIT**: For the sake of your precious time reading about wth is locator value, here is my *homemade backronym*:

- lvalue: location value, you know the location of it.
- rvalue: read value, you can only read the value.

don't blame me if anything gone wrong.

Comment: Interesting observation.  I'd venture a guess that if you delve into operator overloading, then this type of usage might make sense.  Which would explain why it's part of C++ but not C.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371503/why-is-i-considered-an-l-value-but-i-is-not.  I think the top answer has the best reasoning I've seen.  IT wasn't possible to do this in C since C doesn't have references but C++ does so it would be a natural extension.

Comment: I have never seen "locator value" before, and suspect it's a backronym. As far as I know, l-value and r-value originally referred to the left and right side of an assignment expression.

Comment: @TimRandall It's actually in the C99 standard, which surprised me.

Comment: @NathanOliver is there a corresponding "meaning" for r-value?

Comment: In C99 *value of an expression*

Comment: This is definitely a dupe but I can't find the canonical one.

Comment: @ptr_user7813604 If not even veteran users can find it, then we clearly can't blame you for not finding it either. The SO duplicate system isn't great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, prefix `++` giving lvalue is actually very natural.

Because C++ has operator overloading. For most iterators of potentially complicated type, the prefix `++` returns the lvalue of the iterator itself.

Thus for generic programming, it would be inconvenient to make fundamental type a special case.

For example;

```
auto &iter = ++old_iter;
```

wouldn't work if prefix increment of pointer gives an rvalue.

Comment: So principle of least privilege saves the day right? Allowing it to be an lvalue on primitive type doesn't cause any trouble. C is the best, I knew it. (not to offend, C++ is also the best :))

Comment: I'm not buying it.  As far as I can tell, C++ could have the same rule as C and still implement overloaded `++` operators the same way.  It affects how you can *use* the result, not necessarily how you must *compute* the result.